# Primary nav menu would not relocate to the header

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis

I'm using the Genesis framework in wordpress, I have a header set with a logo and a menu that currently is displayed under the header, I want it in the header.

I know about the option to use a custom men and drag it to the menu right widget, but that simply does not work, everything is unticked in the menu settings but it just wouldn't snap there, it just stays under the header.

Comment: without proper description of the issue or little bit code/image we can't help. Post them while posting question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link it will help you

https://my.studiopress.com/snippets/navigation-menus/

OR Use This

```
remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
add_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
```

Answer (score 0):

What actually solved the problem is something I tried before but didn't work.
The first stage is to use the custom menu on the Widgets and drag it to the Menu Right widget, save it and add the menu to it.

In the menu settings, everything has to be ticked off (all the 3 check boxes).

Then I had to insert the logo into the menu right widget and float it to the left to make sure it's aligned properly with the menu.

I hope it helps anyone.